What is this movie featuring hopping vampires?
This was an asian kung fu movie and I distinctly remember a scene where these hopping vampires are hopping towards our heroes in a graveyard. They're doing all this elaborate kung fu to attach these strips of paper onto the vampires foreheads which stops them moving.
I remember one particular move where a hero jumps in front of a vampire, bends over backwards and attaches the strip to a vampire with two fingers over his head. And then shortly after a gust of wind blows off the paper from one of the vampires and he continues hopping.
I'm sure it was fairly recent (as in 90's onwards), and the film Mr.Vampire doesn't ring any bells at all. 
I've gone through this: http://www.imdb.com/list/2O2mC476sGQ/
But there's nothing there that catches my eye.
Anyone any ideas?

That's quite a list. There's a shorter one here (under 'film'); maybe it'll be of help: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChineseVampire

I don't think so. Thought it might be shaolin vs evil dead, but it doesn't ring any bells andi've just watched a graveyard scene in that that's similar to what I described. It's not that though. There's more kung fu in this one.

Given the huge number of these flicks, do you remember any other distinct details that might narrow it down?

I am almost sure that it is actually a film from the Mr. Vampire series, and I'd wager it's the first one. The film features those bits of paper that makes the dead stop moving again. There's a man in the film that has three jumping dead folks in tow, and when the papers were removed from their heads the scene you've mentioned plays out, though it isn't set in a graveyard, it's actually set in a temple. 
The film also features a strong vampire where the exorcist puts strings in its casket to keep it from rising. 

Note that the "strips of paper" are traditional ways to deal with vampires and other undead in China (and probably other eastern countries).  So they wouldn't really be all that unusual in an eastern movie feature vampires/undead.  The OP doesn't seem to think it's Mr. Vampire, though - if you feel strongly that it is, perhaps you could find screenshots or a short example video clip to include as reference?

Actually, after skimming through Mr. Vampire it could be that. I seem to recognise the main characters having to hold their breath to stop some monster getting them, and them holding their breath in ridiculous elaborate ways. I still don't recognise the title though and I'm usually very good with movies.

I'm sure this was Mr. Vampire, it was a popular HK made film and most Cantonese speakers will probably have watched this, if you are 30+ I'd imagine.

It sounds like a movie I read about on Rinkworks a while back called Robo Vampire.
Does the following review sound familiar?
http://www.rinkworks.com/badmovie/reader/455.shtml
